How to set-up password-less `updatedb` on Linux Mint (21.3)?
After setting a password-less updatedb, I am presented with an error:
$ updatedb
/var/lib/plocate/: Permission denied

How can I fix it?

That is just an example error I got latest. I got more of those. But since it is a very long time since I tried to set this up and failed, now I am confident to make it.

I tried too many things to know what helped, so I will just tell you my final settings, comment if needed, or answer yourself if better.
First I created the password-less sudoers file.
sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/updatedb

where I wrote this single line, saved, exited editor:
vlastimil ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/updatedb.plocate


I know what you think, what is this .plocate file, but I can just tell you how I got to it:
$ which updatedb
/usr/bin/updatedb

$ ll /usr/bin/updatedb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 2018-Jun-16 /usr/bin/updatedb -> /etc/alternatives/updatedb

$ ll /etc/alternatives/updatedb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 2022-Aug-05 /etc/alternatives/updatedb -> /usr/sbin/updatedb.plocate

$ file /usr/sbin/updatedb.plocate
/usr/sbin/updatedb.plocate: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=387eb4faf5a2593f9b69a48fa0992df6d56ca13a, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped



Second, I have created an alias for updatedb in my shell (bash).
$ grep updatedb ~/.bash_aliases 
alias updatedb='sudo /usr/sbin/updatedb.plocate'

which will effectively hide the original updatedb command.
You can use escaping like this \updatedb to reach the original command for whatever reason.

Having 1x NVMe 2TB + 1x SATA 4TB SSD with many files, it takes 24 seconds to update the database. It's now better without a password. 
$ time updatedb
real    0m24.141s

